# jQuery set margin-top for fixed header when loading from middle of page

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I have an easy scrolling header that decreases in size (due to decreasing logo height) and sets the margin-top on the body to account for the fixed header.

My problem is when I load the page with the scrollTop() past my header height, the margin-top is set too small - as my image is shrunken.

css:

```
body {
  -webkit-transition: margin-top .2s ease;
  transition: margin-top .2s ease;
}

.site-header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 110;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
  background: rgba(71,117,25,.9);
}

.custom-logo-link img {
  max-height: 75px;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

.scrolling .custom-logo-link img {
  max-height: calc(75px * .8);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(25%);
  transform: translateX(25%);
}
```

jquery:

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function(){

  marginTop();

  function marginTop(){
      var header = jQuery('.site-header');
      var headerHeight = header.height();
      var body = jQuery('body');

      body.css('margin-top', headerHeight);
  }

})
jQuery(window).on('scroll', function(){

  scrolling();

  function scrolling(){
      var header = jQuery('.site-header');
      var headerHeight = header.height();
      var scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
      var flag = true;

      if (scrollTop > headerHeight && flag){

          header.addClass('scrolling');
          flag = false;

      } else {

          header.removeClass('scrolling');
          flag = true;
      }
  }
})
```

dev site: http://www.dev.mediaworksweb.com/cologeo-wp/

Edit:

I realize that it won't work to load my body's margin-top just based on the logo height, if it is scrolled passed my set point. I also don't quite want to set a static height on my header and margin-top on the body/whatever container.

I tried to add a duplicate of my marginTop() function at the else end of my scrolling() function to reset it on reaching the top of the page but it wasn't accurate (probably due to the transitions?).

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: I don't understand your question `I was hoping to solve this fluidly and not set an actual height on the header.` I don't see you setting a height on the header. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I don't want to set the height of the header to like 100px (then could easily set the margin-top to 100px and be fine). I am hoping to adjust the margin-top to the height of the header without it being specifically set.

Answer (score 0):

Well I ended up adding another function (reset_marginTop()) and had to use a timeout to account for my transitions. I didn't quite want to do it this way as it reset the marginTop each time it scrolls to the top of the page. However, this is what I am using if anyone ever looks:

```
jQuery(window).on('scroll', function(){

function reset_marginTop(){
    var body = jQuery('body');
    var bodyMargin = parseInt(body.css('margin-top'));
    var header = jQuery('.site-header');
    var headerHeight = parseInt(header.height());

    if (headerHeight > bodyMargin) {
        body.css('margin-top', headerHeight);
    }

}

scrolling();

  function scrolling(){
      var header = jQuery('.site-header');
      var headerHeight = header.height();
      var scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
      var flag = true;

      if (scrollTop > headerHeight && flag){

          header.addClass('scrolling');
          flag = false;

      } else {

          header.removeClass('scrolling');
          flag = true;

          setTimeout(reset_marginTop, 200);
      }
  }
})
```